# py.test is failing to deal with creating files

Tags: python, pytest

I have a program where I am creating a multitude of LaTeX files one by one. It is important when creating these LaTeX files to check that they can actually compile to a .pdf without error.

To do so it uses `subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '-halt-on-error', tex_file_name])`.

Which returns `0` on a successful compile from a `.tex` to a `.pdf`, and a 1 otherwise.

The problem I am having is that the only circumstance under which this line of code does not do what I think it should do, is when `py.test` runs it. If I run this code from an interpreter, or running a script from the command line, it works. But py.test doesn't.

When `py.test` errors, it leaves behind a log file created by `pdflatex`, which has this error in it:

```
{c:/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file c:/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/up
dmap/pdftex.map): fflush() failed (Bad file descriptor)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am hazarding a guess here that `py.test` is doing *some thing* with the `.tex` file prior to `pdflatex` being able to compile it. But I don't know what.

Temporary files and directories are talked about in the [py.test docs](http://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html). I don't know if they are relevant to my problem, but I have only played around with them briefly.

In case you want to look at the code, a test case looks like this:

```
from a import Foo
from b import Tree
from latex_tester import latex_tester


def test_Foo():
    q1 = foo.Foo()
    latex_tester(Tree(1, q1))
```

and latex_tester looks like this:

```
import uuid
import os
import subprocess


def latex_tester(tree):
    """ Test whether latex is compilable to a PDF.

    """ 

    full_path = r'some_path'
    uid = str(uuid.uuid1())

    file_name = os.path.join(full_path, 'test' + uid + '.tex')

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        _write_tree(f, tree)

    retcode = subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '-halt-on-error', file_name])
    if retcode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("This latex could not be compiled.")
```

Comment: Is `full_path` a relative path or absolute path?

Comment: Can you try to explicitly close the file before the subprocess call executes?

Comment: py.test doesn't mess with files you create unless you're using py.test to create the files. Get the path of the file created by the tests then try to run it manually with that file. I'm betting something is wrong with the file rather than the test.

Comment: The file is already closed automatically when `with` completes.

Comment: @Cixate Do you mean manually run pdflatex on the created .tex file? If that's the case, the latex compiles totally fine when I run pdflatex outside of py.test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, using 'xelatex' instead of 'pdflatex' makes things work as normal.

For any future readers - I have TeXworks installed which presumably installed both these tools. I don't know if xelatex influences the final pdf produced. It seems to be producing a good .pdf

Anyway, I made this answer to my own question since there doesn't seem to be anything else coming and it certainly solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

I'm using C# as programming language for creating the .tex documents and it crashed during pdflatex when I included a image into the pdf.

And it worked if i started it manually...

Error:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file <linktoFile>/file.pdf): fflush() failed (Bad file descriptor)
```

Unfortunately xelatex didn't work either so I searched and eventually stumbled upon it.

Basically the error happened for me at this line:

```
string tex = tex.Replace("\uFFFD\uFFFDMEMNAME\uFFFD\uFFFD", user.Surname)
```

Here user.Surname was null.

When the tex string is saved into the file it mysteriously remembers the null and pdflatex crashes somewhere completely different. If you on the other hand start pdflatex on the same file again manually the null is gone and it works.

The whole mess went away when I entered a Surname and it works now from the program.

Maybe this will help someone with the same problem.